# error trying to crosscompile opencv

Tags: opencv, arm, codeblocks

I'm trying to crosscompile a very simple test program with functions of opencv.

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and Codeblocks, and when i compile my code it appear this to me:

```
||warning: ../../lib/libopencv_core.so, needed by /root/arm-lib/lib/libopencv_highgui.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)|
||warning: ../../lib/libopencv_imgproc.so, needed by /root/arm-lib/lib/libopencv_highgui.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)|
||=== Build finished: 0 errors, 2 warnings ===|
```

And when I try to execute this software in ARM, I get Segmentation fault (core dumped).

The flags that I am using on Codeblocks are:

-L/usr/local/lib
-L/lib/libbxml2.so.2
-lpthread
-lrt
-lxml2
-lz
-lopencv_highgui
-lopencv_core
-lopencv_imgproc

What do you suggest? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One obvious problem with your command line: `-L` must be used only to add the libraries directories, however, you are using it to include a file in `-L/lib/libbxml2.so.2`, and that's just wrong.

Most probably you wanted to do:

```
-L/usr/local/lib -L/lib -lxml2 -lpthread -lrt -lxml2 -lz -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc
```

Now, the error is clear: the system can't find libopencv_core.so and libopencv_imgproc.so in the paths you included with `-L`. I suggest you find these files and then add the appropriate directory using the `-L` flag.

Comment: It's so strange because that files are in the libraries directories, /usr/local/lib, and in /lib. I don't know what's happening

Comment: Finally, I've reinstalled all the libraries, and try to compile again and I can compile, but anyway when I try to execute that software on ARM, I'm getting the same error Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: It's great that you can compile, it means that your question has been answered! If you have new questions (problems) feel free to ask them in new threads. The segfault could be caused by a problem in your code. At this point, it's appropriate for you to review all the answers you received and select the answer that helped you solve your problem (there's a little checkbox near each answer). If none solved your question, you can add an answer yourself.

Comment: Finally, I can run the software that I have developed because I'm transfering files with Filezilla and it don't transfer with binary mode, and that's because I get Segfault. Thanks karlphillip!